# Filtering an array in ember

Tags: ember.js

Ok so I'm fairly new to programing, I know how to run a filter on a JSON Array but I cant seem to figure it out when I'm pulling the data from firebase and viewing it in an Ember app.

this is my route.js code:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
      }
    });
```

This is my template.hbs code the href="#!" is the generic from materialize for the dropdown buttons:

```
    <div class="list-wrapper col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12 button-div">
           {{#md-btn-dropdown text='Filter' class="col-xs-2"            belowOrigin=true}}
               <li><a href="#!">Female</a></li>
               <li><a href="#!">Male</a></li>
               <li><a href="#!">All</a></li>
           {{/md-btn-dropdown}}
        </div>
        {{#each model as |info|}}
        <div class="col-xs-3 user-card">
           <div class="card-info">
               <ul>
                   <li>Last Name- {{info.lastName}}</li>
                   <li>First Name- {{info.firstName}}</li>
                   <li>Gender- {{info.gender}}</li>
                   <li><a href="mailto:{{info.email}}">{{info.email}} </a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
       {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
```

This is my controller.js code which I no is all wrong:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      customFilter: function(gender) {
         return function(el) {
            var r = el.user;
            return r.gender === gender;
         };
      }
    });
```

and this is my model:

```
    import DS from 'ember-data';
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default DS.Model.extend({
      lastName: DS.attr('string'),
      firstName: DS.attr('string'),
      gender: DS.attr('string'),
      email: DS.attr('string')
    });
```

I've searched high and low and I'm sure I'm just missing something basic and stupid. What I want is for the dropdown menu to be able to filter and display only female, male or all. Again I'm new to this stuff so I apologize if this is a pretty basic thing. Thank You

Comment: The [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/enumerables/#toc_filtering) is a good place to start when you are new to something.

Answer (score 1):

What your missing is an action that updates your controller when an item in the dropdown is actually selected.

Some helpful reading:

- [Triggering changes with actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/)
- [Computed Properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/object-model/computed-properties/)

Here's how to put actions in your dropdown component

```
  {{#md-btn-dropdown text='Filter' class="col-xs-2" belowOrigin=true}}
               <li><a {{action "filterUpdated" "female"}}>Female</a></li>
               <li><a {{action "filterUpdated" "male"}}>Male</a></li>
               <li><a {{action "filterUpdated"}}>All</a></li>
   {{/md-btn-dropdown}}
```

In your controller you then need to handle this action like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  // the people property is an alias of the model object
  // which essentially makes people a synonym for model
  // read more http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_alias
  people: Ember.computed.alias('model'),

  // holds the currently selected gender, e.g., "female". A null value indicates there is no filter.
  currentFilter: null,

  /*
   filteredPeople is a computed array containing people models.
   The array is recomputed every time the model changes or the currentFilter changes,
   see the .property() bit at the end.
   read more: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_filter
   */
  filteredPeople: Ember.computed.filter('people', function(person/*, index, array*/) {
    // this function is passed each item in the model array, i.e., the person argument
    // there's no need to use the index nor array arguments, so I've commented them out
    if(this.get('currentFilter') === null) {
      // when the filter is null, we don't filter any items from the array
      return true;
    } else {
      // otherwise only return true if the gender matches the current filter
      return person.gender === this.get('currentFilter');
    }
  }).property('people', 'currentFilter'),

  actions: {
    filterUpdated: function (value) {
      if (Ember.isEmpty(value)) {
        // an empty value means we should clear the filter
        this.set('currentFilter', null);
      }
      else {
        this.set('currentFilter', value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Finally, edit your template to change

```
 {{#each model as |info|}}
```

to

```
{{#each filteredPeople as |info|}}
```

Also at a meta level, don't apologize for asking questions! Everyone is new at something at somepoint, and often asking is the best way to learn. That's what stackoverflow is all about :)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this and received no errors up until I attempt to select a filter and then I receive an action handler error.

Comment: Actual error: Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'filteredPeople'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

Comment: In your dropdown did you set `filterUpdated` as the action for each item? From the error it looks like it's set to `filteredPeople`.

Comment: I'm the template did you write {{action "filterUpdated" ..}}. or {{action "filteredPeople" ..}} It should be the first one.

Comment: Just added a missing bit about changing the {{#each}} line. See the "Finally, " above.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work:

```
gender: 'All',
filteredModel: Ember.computed.filter('model', function(person) {
  return person.gender === this.get('gender');
}).property('gender'),
```

this assumes that it starts on all, and then when the dropdown changes the value of gender, then the filteredModel will get updated.  You can then in your hbs file change the result to:

```
{{#each filteredModel as |info|}}
```